# expo Ios build not building after adding react native google mobile ads

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

This is my app.config.json

```
export default {
name: “Tarrhoon”,
slug: “social_assistance”,
version: “1.3.0”,
orientation: “portrait”,
icon: “./assets/appicon.png”,
splash: {
image: “./assets/splash.png”,
resizeMode: “cover”,
},
plugins: [
[
“expo-notifications”,
{
icon: “./assets/splashlogo.png”,
color: “#ffffff”,
},
],
[
“expo-media-library”,
{
photosPermission: “Allow Social Assistance to access your photos.”,
savePhotosPermission: “Allow Social Assistance to save photos.”,
isAccessMediaLocationEnabled: true,
},
],
[
“expo-image-picker”,
{
photosPermission:
“The app accesses your photos to let you share them With the Admin”,
},
],
[
“expo-av”,
{
microphonePermission: “Allow App to access your microphone.”,
},
],
],
android: {
versionCode: 3,
icon: “./assets/simpleicon.png”,
googleServicesFile: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICES_JSON,
adaptiveIcon: {
foregroundImage: “./assets/appicon.png”,
backgroundColor: “#7369ef”,
},
package: “com.muhammad1700.social_assistance”,
permissions: [
“android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”,
“android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”,
“android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION”,
“android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO”,
“android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS”,
],
},
ios: {
icon: “./assets/simpleicon.png”,
supportsTablet: true,
infoPlist: {
NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription:
“Allow Social Assistance to access your photos.”,
NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription:
“Allow Social Assistance to save photos.”,
},
bundleIdentifier: “com.muhammad1700.social-assistance”,
},
extra: {
eas: {
projectId:process.env.PROJECT_ID,
},
},
“react-native-google-mobile-ads”: {
“android_app_id”: process.env.ANDROID_APPID,
“ios_app_id”: process.env.IOS_APPID
},
};
```

the app builds fine on android but doesnt build on ios and throws the following error

````
:x: (node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/ios/RNGoogleMobileAds/RNGoogleMobileAdsModule.mm:120:85)

** 118 | if (requestConfiguration[@“tagForChildDirectedTreatment”]) {**
** 119 | BOOL tag = [requestConfiguration[@“tagForChildDirectedTreatment”] boolValue];**
> 120 | GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.tagForChildDirectedTreatment = tag;
** | ^ incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to ‘NSNumber * _Nullable’ from ‘BOOL’ **
** 121 | }**
** 122 | **
** 123 | if (requestConfiguration[@“tagForUnderAgeOfConsent”]) {**
```

1065

```
:x: (node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/ios/RNGoogleMobileAds/RNGoogleMobileAdsModule.mm:125:80)

** 123 | if (requestConfiguration[@“tagForUnderAgeOfConsent”]) {**
** 124 | BOOL tag = [requestConfiguration[@“tagForUnderAgeOfConsent”] boolValue];**
> 125 | GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.tagForUnderAgeOfConsent = tag;
** | ^ incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to ‘NSNumber * _Nullable’ from ‘BOOL’ **
** 126 | }**
** 127 | **
** 128 | if (requestConfiguration[@“testDeviceIdentifiers”]) {**
```

1066

** ** Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')** **

1067

** ** Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Tarrhoon' from project 'Tarrhoon')** **

1068

** ** Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Tarrhoon' from project 'Tarrhoon')** **

1069

** ** Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNGoogleMobileAds] Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Tarrhoon' from project 'Tarrhoon')** **

1070

** **▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **** **

1071

** **▸ The following build commands failed:** **

1072

** **▸ CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tarrhoon-gbsktiwukxvwhqcwkcfyzdyusrux/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Tarrhoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNGoogleMobileAds.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNGoogleMobileAdsModule.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/ios/RNGoogleMobileAds/RNGoogleMobileAdsModule.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNGoogleMobileAds' from project 'Pods')** **

1073

** **▸ (1 failure)** **

1074

** **** ARCHIVE FAILED **** **

1075

```

```

1076

```

```

1077

** **The following build commands failed:** **

1078

** ** CompileC /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tarrhoon-gbsktiwukxvwhqcwkcfyzdyusrux/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Tarrhoon/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/RNGoogleMobileAds.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNGoogleMobileAdsModule.o /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-google-mobile-ads/ios/RNGoogleMobileAds/RNGoogleMobileAdsModule.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNGoogleMobileAds' from project 'Pods')** **

1079

** **(1 failure)** **

1080

** **Exit status: 65** **

1081

```

```

1082

** **+-------------+-------------------------+** **

1083

** **| Build environment |** **

1084

** **+-------------+-------------------------+** **

1085

** **| xcode_path | /Applications/Xcode.app |** **

1086

** **| gym_version | 2.211.0 |** **

1087

** **| sdk | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk |** **

1088

** **+-------------+-------------------------+** **

1089

```

```

1090

** **Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project** **

1091

** **It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how** **

1092

** **to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/** **

1093

** **Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make** **

1094

** **sure your project is set up correctly.** **

1095

** **fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the** **

1096

** **the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.** **

1097

** **Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there** **

1098

```

```

1099

[stderr]

** **[!] Error building the application - see the log above** **

1100

** **Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.** **emphasized text
````

i can provide more information kindly help[image]

i tried everything according to docs but nothing seems to work,  any help will be appreciated as i dont have enough time and deadline is around the corner ,idont understand why it throws the error on ios only and not on ios . when i build for android it builds Ok .